# Error : In fetching data from DatabaseClosed Connection

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing a strange problem while running two test-cases that is present in a TestSuite. The Test suite comprises of 15 Test cases, and these two are 9th and 10 th Tc's respectively.

When i am running only these two test cases both are running fine, but with the whole test suite running these two are not present in the report.(Totally getting skipped)

Both the test cases having a function that executes a databases query and fetches a patient name from database and in console we have seen this is the root cause behind the error.
We are facing "Error :In fetching data from Database Io exception: Connection reset"--9th Tc
                               In fetching data from DatabaseClosed Connection"--10th Tc

The code we have written is below to fetch the patient name:

```
            try
    {
        stmt =con.createStatement(); //public static java.sql.Statement stmt;public static ResultSet rs;public static Connection con; these 3 we declared in driver script

        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select d.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, d.ssn from Table1 d, Table2 c  where c.id=d.contact_id and d.facility_id='"+facilityID+"' and d.security_id='"+securityID+"' and <Some condition> and d.id not in (<Some data>);
        if (rs.next() == true){
            DBFirstName=rs.getString(2);
            DBLastName=rs.getString(3);
            DBFullName = DBLastName +", " +DBFirstName;
            System.out.println("DB Full Name ="+DBFullName);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Inside else"); 
            return "Fail :Unable to fetch Patient data(lastname) from database";
        }
    }

    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Error : In fetching data from Database" +t.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Error : In fetching data from Database" +t.getMessage());
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
```

Please let me know if anyone having any idea. 
Thanks in advance.
Nilanjan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if database connection has been open . Con.open() might do the work. And also try checking the stack trace i guess it is coming as soon as you start using the connection as it is not open. Please check and tell

Comment: Yes, that was the issue I figured out. Thanks.